# display data from database, edit it, but when click on previous page, the data gone.

Tags: php, jquery, html

i got 4 pages which are company details, job requirements, job responsibilities and design. so im gonna update the data from these pages. so i retrieve the data from database to be display into form for these 4 pages. after i edit the values on first page, then i go to next page for next update. but when i go back to previous page, the data wont keep the edited value but display the old data that i retrieved from database. so how to prevent this to happen ? same goes if i refresh the pages. i know i can use the session to store edited value but still i think that form will display the old data. help me give the idea how to do this pls ! thanks

Comment: Please check values are updated at table.

Comment: You said you are using SESSION variables for data storage . Have you started your session at the beginning of your code using `session_start()` - (From my Experience - PHP wont warn you regarding absence of session_start() irrespective of your usage of SESSION variables )

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow below steps

1. Go to next page by submit & action attribute
2. In next page hold all the post value into hidden fields
3. Use a back button to go back.
4. when go button will be pressed submit the form which is holding the hidden fields
5. Now you are in first page and simply use $_REQUEST or $_POST to get the previous value.

Hope you under stand.

N.B: If you use browser back button browser will ask you to confirm to resubmit the form. If you confirm then no problem but if you didn't confirm then you lost your values.

Comment: if i save the data into database before to next page, but how about after the user go to next page, then he decide to cancel the edit. so does that meaning the data from first page is already inserted to database even he decide to cancel the edit at 2nd page ? so the old data will not be display at first page as it has been overwrite by new data in database even he's cancelling the edit. i hope u understand what i mean.

Comment: so how about the php echo value at the first page ? as it will display the old data before the user edit the value. by using $_REQUEST or $_POST, then it will overwrite the old data or still displaying old data even he back to previous page ? how bout if th user jump to another tab without clicking on go button ?

Comment: use value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['name']; ?>" on every pages

Comment: okay. using value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['name']; ?>" is working for my coding if i back to previous page. but then, i need to display old data first before i edit. for example:

this is for display from old data.(first page)
<input type="text" name="jobTitle" size="70%" value="<?php echo $job_title2; ?>">

jobtitle = account manager
new jobtitle = account
then i go to next page after hit next button. but when i go back to previous page using back button, it show old data which is account manager. not the current edited value(account). do u get what i mean ?

Comment: It should be <input type="text" name="jobTitle" size="70%" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['job_title2']; ?>">